# What is the different between require, require.resolve, webpack.ProvidePlugin and webpack.DefinePlugin

Tags: webpack, webpack-3, webpack-plugin

I'm doing a project using webpack, angularjs.
In the webpack.config.js, I've seen sometimes they use:

In **app.js**

```
require('angular')
```

In **webpack.config.js**

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'require.specified': 'require.resolve'
}
```

In **webpack.config.js**

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    Promise: 'bluebird'
}
```

In **webpack.config.js**

```
{
                test: require.resolve('rxjs/bundles/Rx'),
                use:[
                    {
                        loader: 'expose-loader',
                        options: 'Rx'
                    }
                ]
            }
```

I don't understand what are their differences. When should I use `require`, `require.resolve`, `webpack.DefinePlugin`, `webpack.ProvidePlugin`

Can anyone help me please ?

Thank you